# Has anyone tried to condense Naruto?

Tags: naruto

It occurs to me that Naruto suffers from the fact that although over the entire series a lot happens, in the average 20 minute episode there is usually 5 minutes of content and 15 minutes of pointless filler (I'm talking about repeating frames of combat, and scenes where not much is happening or previous episodes are recapped)

I was wondering if there was an abridged Naruto effort to cut all this chaff out?

Comment: You shouldd try the Manga then. With the anime(not just Naruto), you really need to be patient and take in all this with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Even the manga, however, has its share of extended scenes. In recent chapters, we may see 5 pages of bloodstains for one attack.

Comment: The manga also relies on a lot of back story.

Comment: There are [fan-made abridged](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE04C5C6D0F83F865) versions of the series.

Answer (score 2):

There are abridged versions available online though I can't guarantee you their ingenuity. I'd suggest reading the manga and from personal experience I can tell you that I finish at least about 7 chapters (that's like about 10 episodes on an average considering fillers) in the time it takes me to watch one episode.